# Google Maps disable clickable polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating some markers and polygons on google maps in a Google App Script project. I want to be able to toggle all the map objects being clickable, and not clickable. I'm using the marker property of 'clickable' to do this, by altering between true and false. Weirdly though, I've found that you also have to set the title property of the marker (if it has one) to '', otherwise this process doesn't work.

However, to force the clickable state of markers currently shown on the map, it requires you to essentially set the 'map' of the marker to null (using setMap), and then to add the 'map' back again. This process of nulling the map in the marker, and then adding it back works great for markers, but doesn't seem to work for polygons.

I can manually force this to work by applying the click state, but then manually removing the polygons from the map (I have a checkbox by the map to do this, which does just use setMap(null)), and manually adding them back in (using setMap(map)). And the process works no problem.

But it's this process of running the code sequentially...

```
markers[i].setMap(null)
markers[i].setMap(map)
```

... which doesn't work for polygons, but does for markers. Any ideas?

For reference my polygon objects is formed like this...

```
        // Construct the polygon
        var olsObject = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: mvcArr,
          strokeColor: hexOLSCol,
          strokeOpacity: lineOpacity,
          strokeWeight: 1.0,
          fillColor: hexOLSCol,
          fillOpacity: surfOpacity,
          zIndex : zind,
          title: tempRwy.name[j],
          content: htmlStr,
          clickable: true,
        });
          
      // add marker to global array
      markers.push(olsObject)
```

Comment: No you don't need to remove / add them back to the map and that is true for both Markers and Polygons. Loop through your markers or polygons array and use `markers[i].setOptions({ clickable: false })` (or `true` depending on what you are after). Btw. I would suggest you don't push Polygons to an array called "markers" for clarity.

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you, easy when you know how, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MrUpisdown, the answer is to use...

```
markers[i].setOptions({ clickable: false })
```

instead of directly altering the marker setting. By using this, markers (or polygons) don't then be removed or added back to the map to enable the click state.